# Why is the minimum number of acute exterior angles in a convex octagon independent of whether the octagon has equal-sides?

Tags: geometry, independence, angle, polygons

Why is the minimum number of acute exterior angles in a convex octagon independent of whether the octagon has equal-sides?

In particular, I know five is the number of acute exterior angles in a convex octagon, and three are obtuse.

Comment: If the octogon is a regular one with equal sides and equal angles between sides, then all of the exterior angles are $45^\circ$. A regular octogon is convex, so I don't think this question is correct.

Comment: @SuzuHirose The question was about equal sides, not equal angles. Although the question probably could be worded better, I think the idea is initially that you can make any irregular convex octagon you want in order to establish the minimum number of acute exterior angles, but the minimum is still $5$ even if we add the constraint that the sides must all be equal length.

Comment: @DavidK My comment is a counterexample to the claim in the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: @SuzuHirose As I said, it could be worded better. The second paragraph assumes you have constructed an octagon in order to achieve the minimum mentioned in the first paragraph. I suppose in this case you could argue that it really **needs** to be worded better in order to prevent the second paragraph being interpreted as a statement in isolation (in which case it's clearly false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any convex polygon, the total exterior angle is $360^\circ$. [Proof: let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 ...$ be the interior angles, then $\sum _i(180-\angle\alpha_i)=180n-\sum_i\angle\alpha_i=180n-(n-2)180=360$].

Now there cannot be four exterior angles $\geq 90$: otherwise they already add to $\geq 360$, which implies these four exterior angles are all $90$ and the remaining exterior angles are $0$, that is absurd (if $n>4$). In conclusion, for convex polygons with $n>4$ sides, there are at most three non-acute exterior angles, the remaining $n-3$
many exterior angles are acute. It is easy to construct an $n$-gon with exactly n-3 acute exterior angles.